# Sort Descending by Date created_at

Tags: javascript, django

I have a list of proposals that I want to sort descending by date created_at. How would I go about achieving that?

```
<div class="display-title">
 <p class="proposal-title-display">
 {% if proposal.data.title %}
 {{ proposal.data.title }}
 {% else %}
 My proposal
 {% endif %}
 started at: {{proposal.created_at}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to do this in views.py, something like this: `MODEL.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')`

Comment: Where's the list of proposals? you're only showing the template displaying one proposal. In your view, when you fetch the proposals, you can just order them with [`order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: Will try that. Thanks all.